# Add or remove validation rules and message

Tags: javascript

I've below code and i trying to change validation rules and its message dynamically. But, i'm doing something wrong so that my code is not working as i want. i need to do when user select united state country then my validation rule will work for drop down of states and for any other countries  the rule will work for input box of state field. but i am not able to change validation message dynamically also the rules not modifying properly

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    
   
    var validator = $("#useform").validate({
        rules: {
            phone: {"required": true, "maxlength": 15, digits: true, "minlength": 10},
            fax: {"required": true, "maxlength": 15, digits: true, "minlength": 10},
            country:"required",
            zip: {"required": true, "maxlength": 15,"minlength": 5},
        },
        messages: {

            phone: {required:"Phone is required",maxlength:"Maximum 15 characters required",minlength:"Minimum 10 characters required"},
            fax: {required:"Fax is required",maxlength:"Maximum 15 characters allowed",minlength:"Minimum 10 characters required"},
            country: "Country is required",
            state: "State is required",
            zip: {digits:"ZIP should be numeric", required:"ZIP is required",maxlength:"Maximum 15 characters allowed",minlength:"Minimum 5 characters required"},
            sel_state: {required: "State is required"},
        }
    });

    if($('#country').val() == 'us')
    {
        $( "#zip" ).rules( "add", {
            digits : true
          });

        
          
    }
    else{
        
    }
  
});



function checkCountryState(value) {
    
 
 if($('#country').val() == 'us')
    {  
    $('#state').hide();
     $('#sel_state').show();
    $( "#sel_state" ).rules( "add", {
            required : true
          });
          $( "#state" ).rules( "remove", 
            "required" 
          );
    }
    else{
        $('#state').show();
     
          $( "#sel_state" ).rules( "remove", "required");
          $( "#state" ).rules( "add", 
          {
            required : true
          } 
          );
          $('#sel_state').hide();
    }  
    
}
```

```html
  <head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.11.1/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>

</head>
  <form class="form-validate"  action="" method="post" name="userform" id="userform" autocomplete="off">
    <div class="row">   
       <div class="col-lg-12">
          <div class="portlet ">                        
                        
              <div class="portlet-body">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-md-12 col-xl-8 my-xl-3">
                    <fieldset class="border h-100 my-xl-0">
                                        
                       <div class="row">
                         <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4">
                           <div class="form-group">
                             <label class="control-label" for="phone">Phone:<span class="require">*</span></label>
                             <div class="input-icon right">                         
<input  name="phone" value="" maxlength="15" id="phone" placeholder="Phone" type="text"  class="form-control required">
                              </div>
                             </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4">
                             <div class="form-group">
                              <label class="control-label" for="fax">Fax:<span class="require">*</span></label>
                              <div class="input-icon right">
                               <input name="fax" value="" id="fax" placeholder="Fax" type="text" class="form-control required"  maxlength="15" > 
                              </div>
                             </div>
                            </div>


                                          
                          <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label class="control-label" for="country">Country:<span class="require">*</span></label>
                                  <div class="input-icon right">            
                                      <!--                                                        remove_validation(this.id), renderStateForBilling(this.value);-->
                                      <select name="country" id="country" class="form-control custom-select" onchange="checkCountryState(this.value);">
                                          <option value="">--Select--</option>
                                         <option value="us">Unieted States</option>
                                          <option value="uk">Unieted Kingdom</option>
                                           <option value="in">India</option>
                                      </select>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>

                          <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4">
                              <div class="form-group">
                                  <label class="control-label" for="state">State:<span class="require">*</span></label>
                                  <div class="input-icon right">                                                


                                      <input name="state" value="" id="state" type="text" class="form-control" style="display:none">                                                
                                      <select data-selected-state="" name="sel_state" id="sel_state" class="form-control custom-select   required phone-group"  >
                                          <option>--Select--</option>
                                          <option value="Alabam">Alabam</option>
                                          <option value="Alaska">Alaska</option>
                                          <option value="Arizona">Arizona</option>

                                      </select>
                                  </div>
                              </div>
                          </div>
                          <div class="col-md-6 col-xl-4">
                          <div class="form-group">
                            <label class="control-label" for="zip">Zip:<span class='require'>*</span></label>
                            <div class="input-icon right">

                                <input name="zip" value="" placeholder="Zip" id="zip" type="text" class="form-control " maxlength="15" > 
                            </div>
                          </div>
                          </div>
                                            
                                           

                                            
                  </div>
                </fieldset>
              </div>

            </div>  
          </div>                        
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12 text-right px-0">
          <div class="row mx-0">
              <div class="col-md-12">       

                  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success"  value="Save"/>
              </div>
          </div>    
      </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `depends` option (vaguely documented under [`rules`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#rules)) as in:

```js
rules: {
  // ...
  state: {
    required: {
      depends: el => $('#country').val() == 'us',
    }
  },
  // ...
},
```

Dynamic messages can be done in a similar way (described under [`messages`](https://jqueryvalidation.org/validate/#messages)):

```js
messages: {
  // ...
  state: {
    required: el => {
      if($('#country').val() == 'us') return 'State is required';
    },
  },
  // ...
},
```